# Need help calling imagePickerController's "Editing mode"

Tags: ios, camera, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, crop

I've searched everywhere and cannot find a solid answer to this. Is there any way to programatically call a imagePickerController's "edit" photo mode (i.e. the mode where you crop photo taken into a square)?

The reason I'm asking is because I have a custom overlay view and a custom "take photo" button, but I want to edit the image afterwards. I have set the allowsEditing attribute to YES  but

```
[camera takePicture];
```

Just calls the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo right after the image is taken. It doesn't go to the "edit" mode view at all. Is there a solution to this?

My code for the image picker:

```
    camera = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    camera.delegate = self;
    camera.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    camera.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
    camera.showsCameraControls = NO;
    camera.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    camera.toolbarHidden = YES;
    camera.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
    camera.allowsEditing = YES;
    camera.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
```

Edit: added more code

Answer (score -1):

Post your code on how you are presenting the `imagePickerContorller`

`imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;` is what you use to allow editing of the image after image is taken

try adding `[cameraOverlayView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];`

Comment: edited my post and added requested code... I don't think I'm doing anything wrong. Maybe it's not possible with custom overlay?

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. Weirdly enough if I set showCameraControls to YES and use the [imagePicker takePicture] command, I am able to edit the picture. This might be a bug.